# GBQ: SchemaField REPEATED mode writes empty array

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to write a simple dataframe to gbq. One of the field is array so I tried using REPEATED mode. But it seems nothing is written to the array

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'my_string': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        'my_int64': [1, 2, 3],
        'my_float64': [4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
        'my_timestamp': [
            pd.Timestamp("1998-09-04T16:03:14"),
            pd.Timestamp("2010-09-13T12:03:45"),
            pd.Timestamp("2015-10-02T16:00:00")
        ],
        'my_array': [
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9]
        ]
    }
)
# client = bigquery.Client()
table_id = 'junk.pshah2_new_table'
# Since string columns use the "object" dtype, pass in a (partial) schema
# to ensure the correct BigQuery data type.
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(schema=[
    bigquery.SchemaField("my_string", "STRING"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("my_array", "INTEGER","REPEATED"),
])

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    df, table_id, job_config=job_config
)

# Wait for the load job to complete.
job.result()
```

In GBQ I do not find `my_array` written at all
[image]

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What's the current schema of your table in BigQuery? Because your screenshot with my_int64 (and followings) isn't consistent with your code.

Comment: I do not specify a schema. I just set the STRING and ARRAY columns to correct GBQ recognized datatypes. I don't see anything wrong with my_int64 variable.

Comment: Ok, and  you insert this in new table. The schema is autodetected and created. And you have only the issue with your Array, correct? However, i still dont understand your job config in your code. It's not consistent with the result